# After php artisan migrate : Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error after i have installed the code and enter the page :

ErrorException
Illegal offset type in isset or empty (View: modules\Location\Views\frontend\blocks\list-locations\loop.blade.php)

The line that its shows the error on is:

**Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
modules\Location\Models\Location.php:62**

Code:

```
public function getDisplayNumberServiceInLocation($service_type)

        {

            $allServices = get_bookable_services();

            if(empty($allServices[$service_type])) return false;

            $module = new $allServices[$service_type];

            return $module->getNumberServiceInLocation($this);

        }
```

**::require
modules/Location/Views/frontend/blocks/list-locations/loop.blade.php:7**

code:

```
$translation = $row->translateOrOrigin(app()->getLocale());

    $link_location = false;

    if(is_string($service_type)){

        $link_location = $row->getLinkForPageSearch($service_type);

    }
```

I can´t the sollution for the error.

Comment: You need to debug your code... What does `$allServices[$service_type]` return? Your error is saying that whatever that equates to is not compatible with `empty()`, but we don't have access to your code, and you didn't include any debugging details, so I'm not sure how we're supposed to help you beyond pointing out what the error is already telling you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `empty()` you can use `!isset()` function. Your code should be:

```
   public function getDisplayNumberServiceInLocation($service_type)

        {

            $allServices = get_bookable_services();

            if(!isset($allServices[$service_type])) return false;

            $module = new $allServices[$service_type];

            return $module->getNumberServiceInLocation($this);

        }
```